# How do I properly invoke MSYS2 Bash commands using CMake execute_process()?

Tags: bash, shell, cmake, mingw-w64, msys2

### Problem Description

I am having trouble setting up a CMake external_process() command that executes a MSYS2 bash command. When I am in the MSYS2 shell if I run the command `$ bash -v ./bootstrap.sh` the command works correctly. But if I run the CMake script in the MSYS2 shell using `$ cmake -P Run_bash_command.cmake` the command errors out part way through the process. An important piece of information I found in the [CMake Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/execute_process.html) makes me think that I am not invoking bash correctly or missing an environmental variable:

> CMake executes the child process using operating system APIs directly. All arguments are passed VERBATIM to the child process. No intermediate shell is used, so shell operators such as > are treated as normal arguments.

I would like to be able to do this command using CMake if possible as this problem is part of a much larger CMake superbuild project. If there is another approach to solving the problem I am open to suggestions as long as I can include it into the automation of the superbuild project. Any help will be appreciated.

#### Run_bash_command.cmake contents:

```
SET( ENV{MSYSTEM} MINGW64 )
SET( DIR_CONTAINING_BOOTSTRAP_SH C:/bash_test )
SET( BASH_COMMAND_TO_RUN bash -v ./bootstrap.sh )

EXECUTE_PROCESS( COMMAND ${BASH_COMMAND_TO_RUN}
          WORKING_DIRECTORY ${DIR_CONTAINING_BOOTSTRAP_SH} RESULT_VARIABLE command_result )

IF( NOT "${command_result}" STREQUAL "0" )
    MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "Error: command_result='${command_result}'" )
ENDIF()
```

---

### Environment Setup

- I followed the directions to [setup MSYS2](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20installation/) 64bit and added the mingw-w64 toolchain as well as cmake using the command `pacman -S base-devel git mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`
- To run the commands I use the **MinGW-w64 Win64 Shell** that is installed with MSYS2
- The file **bootstrap.sh** comes from the [libusb github repository](https://github.com/libusb/libusb) and the folder **c:/bash_test** contains a clone of the master branch

---

### Output

#### `$ bash -v ./bootstrap.sh` output:

```
$ bash -v ./bootstrap.sh
#!/bin/sh

if ! test -d m4 ; then
    mkdir m4
fi
autoreconf -ivf || exit 1
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh''
...<clipped output due to length>...
configure.ac:29: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:29: installing './missing'
examples/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
```

#### `$ cmake -P Run_bash_command.cmake` output:

```
$ cmake -P Run_bash_command.cmake
#!/bin/sh

if ! test -d m4 ; then
    mkdir m4
fi
autoreconf -ivf || exit 1
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
aclocal-1.15: error: aclocal: file '/msys64/usr/share/aclocal/xsize.m4' does not exist
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
CMake Error at Run_bash_command.cmake:10 (MESSAGE):
  Error: command_result='1'
```

---

#### Things I have tried:

- Substituting `bash -l -c` but this causes the shell to default to the home directory and then it is unable to find the file bootstrap.sh
- Verified the correct version of bash is found by inspecting my environmental PATH varaiable
- Verified MSYS2 and its packages are up to date
- Using `sh` instead of `bash`
- Calling `autoreconf -ivf` directly, but the same issue occurs
- Using Unix style paths instead of Windows style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue using the code below.

#### Run_bash_command.cmake contents:

```
SET( DIR_CONTAINING_BOOTSTRAP_SH /C/bash_test )
SET( BASH_COMMAND_TO_RUN bash -l -c "cd ${DIR_CONTAINING_BOOTSTRAP_SH} && sh ./bootstrap.sh" )

EXECUTE_PROCESS( COMMAND ${BASH_COMMAND_TO_RUN}
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${DIR_CONTAINING_BOOTSTRAP_SH} RESULT_VARIABLE command_result )

IF( NOT "${command_result}" STREQUAL "0" )
    MESSAGE( FATAL_ERROR "Error: command_result='${command_result}'" )
ENDIF()
```

#### Important Notes:

- Using `bash -l` causes the shell to default to the home directory, to get around this I added a change directory `cd <path>` command to get us back to the directory where we want to issue the bash command.
- Using `-c` causes bash to read a command from a string. Since we want to issue two commands, one for change directory and one for running the shell script, we need to use `&&` to chain the commands together as well as use "quotation marks" to make sure the entire command is read properly as a string.